# Adding TabularInline to the User model in django

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to add a TabularInline model in the admin to the User model.

How should I do such a thing ? because I am not respnsible for the registration ?

Can I add inlines to User model ? can I re-register it ?

Comment: http://blog.timc3.com/2010/02/18/extending-djangos-user-admin/ This should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unregister any Model object and re-register it with your custom demands

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, YourCustomAdmin)
```